# Prioritize id selector over an id and class

Tags: html, css

I have a situation in which I load a style with a selector that should be prioritized over another.
The situation looks like the one in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkftfj2n/1/), in which a specific id selector is not being prioritized over another one that uses a class that is under a specific id.

```
--HTML
<div id="cont">
<p class="hello" id="hello">I wish I was blue</p>
</div>

--CSS
#hello {
    color:blue;
}
#cont .hello {
    color:red;
}

Result is red text
```

I'm pretty sure this could be possible without using !important - which I really would like to avoid since this will be maintained by designers with no css skills for A/B testing. I want to make a selector for them that they will only edit it's properties.

Edit: To be clear, the `#hello` selector is injected to the page and I want to change it to one that actually works, but I don't want to change the other selector for that purpose. Of course if I have no choice I will, but it seems reasonable to be that this css is valid as it is and overriding that selector should be possible without modifying it.

Comment: move the `#hello` style down. so it will overwrite without important.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai http://jsfiddle.net/vkftfj2n/2/ didn't seem to help

Comment: @mot: Would it be possible for you to make the `#hello` also as `#cont #hello`? That should solve it. This [CSS Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) has more info on selector specificity.

Comment: You are targeting `.hello` starting with an id, if you just want to target class `.hello` then leave the id out and just do `.hello {}` there are so many ways around this and you just happen to implement the way that it does not work

Comment: @Huangism While I know this can be done differently, there are reason for that selector to be the way it is, and it was coded way before I touched it. I don't wish to change it while I have other reasonable solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to add another id selector to the first set of CSS rules.

```
 #cont #hello {
    color:blue;
   }

 #cont .hello {
    color:red;
   }
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/53q74jah/

In this case the color was overridden in red because you were using just one id selector #hello and that it's less specific than a selector with 2 ids combined or one id and one class combined, like you have done:

```
#cont .hello {
    color:blue;
}
```

One of the things to take into account when writing CSS code, it’s the concept of CSS specificity. Understanding well this concept will avoid you to have to use !important;

As Mozilla Developer Network defines it, specificity is nonetheless:

> Specificity is the means by which a browser decides which property
>   values are the most relevant to an element and gets to be applied.
>   Specificity is only based on the matching rules which are composed of
>   selectors of different sorts.

The following list of selectors is by increasing specificity:

- Universal selectors
- Type selectors
- Class selectors
- Attributes selectors
- Pseudo-classes
- ID selectors
- Inline style

You can measure specificity counting how many selectors are present in a CSS statement.

CSS Specificity can be represented by 4 columns of priority:

> inline=1|0|0|0
>
> id=0|1|0|0
>
> class=0|0|1|0
>
> element=0|0|0|1

Left to right, the highest number takes priority.

[image]

Comment: Glad it was useful to you. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the `:not` selector to exclude the `#hello` element.

Change the first to:

```
#cont .hello:not(#hello) {
    color:red;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/vkftfj2n/5/)

**[More on `:not` from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not)**

> The negation CSS pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation
>   taking a simple selector X as an argument. It matches an element that
>   is not represented by the argument. X must not contain another
>   negation selector, or any pseudo-elements.

---

Alternatively- per the comments below, you can increase the specificity of the second selector whilst providing variations for various contexts:

```
#hello, #cont #hello, #hello.hello {
    color:blue;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/vkftfj2n/6/)

Comment: +1 mate. I really like this option, with the only possible drawback being IE <= 8 support (as usual duh :()

Comment: I have problem with this solution. I want to change only the #hello selector, because the other one is contained in a website that while I can change it, I would hate to do it because I am injecting the #hello selector into the page under certain circumstances, and the page doesn't need to change for these random needs. I wasn't clear about this is my question, I will edit it now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two different selectors. You can keep one:

```
.hello {
    color:red;
}
#cont .hello {
    color:blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vkftfj2n/4/

Comment: May I understand the downvote? You wish you were blue, and, weren't you on my jsfiddle?

Comment: I'd also like to know the reasoning behind the downvote. Honestly, I think using classes over ID's is great; it gives a set of reusable style rules, and if you really need to change something under a specific scope, that's when you can apply #id .class selector rules.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted. I edited my question to further explain my needs, which this solution doesn't meet. While I agree that using classes over ids in these situation is smarter, I have other considerations in this case.